# If $Z \le Z(G)$ and $\overline E \le G/Z$ be quasisimple. Then $\overline N \le Z(\overline E)$ implies $[E',N] \le Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $Z \le Z(G)$. Set $\overline G := G/Z$ and let $E'$ be a perfect subgroup and $N$ be a normal subgroup of $E'$. Suppose
$$ 
 \overline N \le Z(\overline E)
$$
(where $\overline U := UZ/Z$ for $U \le G$) and that $\overline E$ is perfect and $\overline E / Z(\overline E)$ is simple [This is called quasisimple]. Why do we have $[E', N] \le Z$?

Comment: $E'$ is perfect subgroup **of ....**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that $E\leq G$ and that $E'=[E,E]$.

Recall that for $S,T \leq G$ subgroups of a group $G$, for $K$ a normal subgroup of $G$ and $q:G\to G/K$ the canonical quotient:

- $[q(S),q(T)]=q([S,T])$ and hence;
- $[q(S),q(T)]=0$ if and only if $[S,T]\leq K$.

Now let $q:G\to \bar{G}$ be the canonical quotient. We have $$[q(E'),q(N)] = [[q(E),q(E)],\bar{N}]=[[\bar{E},\bar{E}],\bar{N}]=[\bar{E},\bar{N}]$$
which is trivial since $\bar{N} \leq Z(\bar{E})$. As recalled above this means that $[E',N] \leq Z$.